# Custom Button for Redirecting to another vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, redirect

I want to create a custom save button.By Clicking this button, I should save the record and redirect to another VF page which I created to view.
Please give me suggestions How to perform redirecting and saving the record in one button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish the desired functionality, you are going to want to use the PageReference class to do something like this:

```
 public PageReference save() {
    // Add the account to the database. 
    insert account;
    // Send the user to the custom visualforce page for the new account.
    PageReference acctPage = new PageReference('/apex/myVfAccountPage?Id='+account.Id);
    acctPage.setRedirect(true);
    return acctPage;
}
```

You can check out the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm)